# I wrote a function to merge two arrays into a single array but I'm getting "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to take 2 arrays and merge them into one new array that will combine the objects of each array. I understand how to combine 2 arrays into 1 large one, but I'm having trouble combining the actual objects into a new object within that array. An example of the input and intended output I am trying to get is listed below:

Given arrays:

array1 = ['1','2','3'];

array2 = ['a','b','c'];

New outputted array should be:

array3 = ['1a','2b','3c'];

Here is what i have attempted to do so far.  In this example, I am trying to create the deck of cards needed to play a game of euchre (should have the cards 9, 10, Jack, Queen, and Ace and the suits of Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, and Spades for each card for a total of 24 card combinations).  I created 2 arrays (one for the card 'value' and one for the card 'suits.'  For my function, I am passing both of these decks into a for loop that will ideally append the object of the 'suits' array to the end of the 'values' array. This new list is then passed into the empty 'deck' array to return the new array.  However, I am getting and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')." This is occuring at the beginning of my function 'createDeck' and when I try to call the function in the console log statement at the bottom.  Any assistance in understanding the logic I would need to use to combine these arrays would be greatly appreciated as I am just beginning to work with functions and arrays.

```
const values = ['9','10', 'J', 'Q', 'K','A'];
const suits =  ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'];

function createDeck(values, suits) {

  let deck = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {

    for (let x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {

        let card = {Value: values[x], Suit: suits[i]};

        deck.push(card);
    }

}

  return deck;
}

console.log(createDeck());
```

Comment: Your approach is fine in general, but you need to fix your function parameters / arguments. You're declaring `function createDeck(values, suits)` which means `values` and `suits` are now shadowing the outer consts and inside the function instead hold what you're passing into the function call. Which is nothing: `createDeck()`. Just remove the parameters from the declaration and it should work.

Comment: Which means this question is not at all about combining two arrays, it's about how to properly declare and write a function either with or without arguments: https://jsfiddle.net/pvczk8xq/

Comment: Edited the question title so people don't keep posting unrelated answers / dupes

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for the clarification on how I was declaring my function.  I apologize for the confusion as I though that was how I passed the information into the function.  I just started learning JS and I'm still getting used to the syntax of it all.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry, I was confused by this as well when I started out :)

Answer (score 0):

try to declare a new array and in the for loop do

```
array[i] = values[i] + suits[i]
```

maybe you need to add "" in the array with strings

Comment: No. No. Please read the comments above.

Comment: @ChrisG Why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @James Because an explanation how functions work doesn't belong on stackoverflow. It's a fundamental programming concept and as such gravely OT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array with the map method.

```
const values = ['1','2', '3'];
const suits =  ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function createDeck() {
  let customArray = [];
  
  // check for equality of array lengths
  if (values.length === suits.length) {
    // create a new array with the map method
    customArray = values.map((value, index) => {
      return value + suits[index]
    })
  }

  return customArray;
}

console.log(createDeck())
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use [Array.prototype.map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve your expected results. Length of arrays is assumed equal to each other. A sample code is given as below:

```js
array1 = ['1','2','3'];
array2 = ['a','b','c'];
combineArrays = (arr1,arr2) => {
    const arr = arr1.map((elem,index)=> {
        elem += arr2[index];
        return elem
    })
    return arr
}
console.log(combineArrays(array1, array2))  // ['1a','2b','3c']
```

For loop version is:

```js
array1 = ['1','2', '3']
array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
combineArrays = (arr1,arr2) => {
    const deck = []
    for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
        deck.push(arr1[i] + arr2[i])
    }
    return deck
}
console.log(combineArrays(array1, array2))  // ['1a','2b','3c']
```